# viewModel closure does not work as expected

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui, closures

I have a page to show records and when the user taps each one the dialog shows the options for the tapped record, also all the records have the same options.

I want to declare my options in view when the user taps each record the closure of that option fires automatically.

This is my whole view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecordsView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var recordManager = RecordManager.shared
    @State private var selection: Set<Record> = []
    @State private var showingDeleteAllAlert = false
    @State private var showingOptions = false
    @State private var optionSelected: OptionViewEnum? = nil
    @State private var showingSignalView = false

    private enum OptionViewEnum: String {
        case signal, interpretation, pdf
    }

    private struct Option: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var title: String
        var action: (() -> Void)?
        var navigation: ((OptionViewEnum) -> Void)?
        var destiation: OptionViewEnum?
    }

    private var options: Array<Option> = []

    init() {
        options = [
            Option(id: 1, title: "Signal View", action: nil, navigation: navigate, destiation: .signal),
            Option(id: 2, title: "Interpretation", action: nil, navigation: navigate, destiation: .interpretation),
            Option(id: 3, title: "PDF View", action: nil, navigation: navigate, destiation: .pdf),
            Option(id: 4, title: "Resend", action: resendRecord, navigation: nil, destiation: nil),
            Option(id: 5, title: "Delete", action: deleteRecord, navigation: nil, destiation: nil)
        ]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink("", destination: SignalView(), tag: .signal, selection: $optionSelected)
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0)

                NavigationLink("", destination: AlgorithmView(), tag: .interpretation, selection: $optionSelected)
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0)

                NavigationLink("", destination: PDFView(), tag: .pdf, selection: $optionSelected)
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0)

                List(selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(recordManager.records, id: \.self) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            showingOptions = true
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: item.isSynced ? "icloud.fill" : "icloud.slash")
                                    .foregroundColor(item.isSynced ? .green : .red)
                                Text(item.name)
                                    .lineLimit(1)
                            }
                            .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                        }
                        .confirmationDialog("\(item.name)", isPresented: $showingOptions, titleVisibility: .visible) {

                            ForEach(options) { option in
                                Button(option.title) {
                                    if let navigate = option.navigation, let dest = option.destiation {
                                        navigate(dest)
                                    } else if let action = option.action {
                                        action()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Records")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        if recordManager.records.count > 0 {
                            Button("Delete All") {
                                showingDeleteAllAlert = true
                            }
                            .alert("Are you sure to delete all records?", isPresented: $showingDeleteAllAlert) {
                                Button("No", role: .cancel) { }
                                Button("Yes", role: .destructive) { }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension RecordsView {
    private func navigate(to dest: OptionViewEnum) -> Void {
        self.optionSelected = dest
    }

    private func resendRecord() {
    }

    private func deleteRecord() {
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when I want to set `optionSelected` in the `navigate(to:)` function it doesn't work, `self.optionSelected` is always `nil`.

Comment: I can’t see that you call navigate(to:) anywhere in your code

Comment: What happens it you put print(dest) inside the `private func navigate(to dest: OptionViewEnum) -> Void` and click the first button (i.e destiation = .signal) does it prints it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I pass the `navigate` function in initializing Option! and pass the argument in the `Button` action 
`if let navigate = option.navigation, let dest = option.destiation { navigate(dest) } else if let action = option.action { action() }`

Comment: That’s `navigate()` and not `navigate(to:)` you are calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue resides in keeping a reference of `navigate(to:)` into the `Option` struct.

```
Option(id:..., navigation: navigate,...)
```

By doing so, the current `RecordsView` instance is captured into the closure.

However, SwiftUI creates new copies of its views' structs whenever it needs to update or redraw.
So, whenever it's time to call the closure stored in `Option`, it will be using an invalid copy of `RecordsView` instead of the one SwiftUI is actually using for the UI.

To see what is going on, add the following to your code, and run it in **Release** mode:

```
...

Button(option.title) {
    if let navigate = option.navigation, let dest = option.destiation {
        withUnsafePointer(to: self) { print("Current View: \($0)") } // <--
        navigate(dest)
    }

...

private func navigate(to dest: OptionViewEnum) -> Void {
    withUnsafePointer(to: self) { print("Captured View: \($0)") } // <--
    self.optionSelected = dest
}

...

// Current View: 0x000000016b7e1e90
// Captured View: 0x000000016b7e1de0
```

See how both addresses differ.

Now instead of calling `Option`'s `navigation`, let's actually call current `RecordsView`'s `navigate(to:)`:

```
...

Button(option.title) {
    if let navigate = option.navigation, let dest = option.destiation {
        withUnsafePointer(to: self) { print("Current View: \($0)") }
        //navigate(dest)
        self.navigate(to: dest)
    }

...

// Current View: 0x000000016f161e80
// Captured View: 0x000000016f161e80
```

Now both addresses match. Moreover, the app navigated to the correct destination.

Note that this would also happen to `Option`'s `action`.

So, instead of storing them in `Option` as closures, follow another approach to make sure it interacts with the current View.

For example (and this is just an option), you could model them as an `Enum`:

```
...

private struct Option: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var action: Action
        
    enum Action {
        case navigate(OptionViewEnum)
        case resend
        case delete
    }
}

...

init() {
    options = [
        Option(id: 1, title: "Signal View", action: .navigate(.signal)),
        Option(id: 2, title: "Interpretation", action: .navigate(.interpretation)),
        Option(id: 3, title: "PDF View", action: .navigate(.pdf)),
        Option(id: 4, title: "Resend", action: .resend),
        Option(id: 5, title: "Delete", action: .delete)
    ]
}

...

Button(option.title) {
    switch option.action {
    case let .navigate(destination):
        navigate(to: destination)
    case .resend:
        resendRecord()
    case .delete:
        deleteRecord()
    }
}

...
```

Comment: Nice trick to use params in `switch case`! thank you so much.